# Identify free text keyword duplicates with percentage match

Tags: awk, duplicates, sphinx, percentage, freetext

There are several name titles in my database that gets created and recreated with minor changes very often. With manual eyeballing one can easily identify them as duplicates with minor spelling changes. For e.g.

```
 Resort Inn, Res Ort inn, Rsort Inn etc
```

and so on. What I am looking for is a solution that gives a percentage match of the keywords that am searching for as duplicates.The source set may not be big enough but the reference set can go into millions of data. So a potential mysql "match against" is not scalable. Also the reference set is in mysql and sphinx indexed. The current duplication logic doesnt quite capture all duplicates. For e.g

```
Moy Knn Resort
Moy-Knn
Moy Knn Resort
Moeyy-Knn American Food
```

All these are duplicates according to me. But the fourth is not getting captured at all. I understand they look identical but some percentage number after comparison by eliminating vowels and other things would help. The solution preferred mostly will be with 'php-sphinx' since most of it is already ready or awk (if possible and moderately comfortable too). If not, any open source (python/perl etc) logic will do.

Comment: Do you mean "I understand they [don't] look identical" - missed the word out?

Comment: Yes, "don't" is missing

Answer (score 0):

Well can use something like
http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php
to give you an actual 'percentage'.

But persumably you want some sort of 'first pass' match, to give you likely candidates (so don't need to run levenshtein over millions of rows),

frankly I think will struggle to get something working in Sphinx, particully considering your last example. That is very different. The only thing that might help is 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology
and the Soundex/metaphone systems, there is a small chance that your 'similar' words will actully 'sound' the same.

Comment: Indexing with morphology criteria didn't help. Manually eye balled some cases and felt getting rid of the vowels as well as trimming the leading and trailing multiple letters to single letter could get me closer to a match. Maybe then with filtered data+morphology criteria could work. Will post my findings though I would love to hear about a better method.